# rbind multiple csv file with different colnames R

Tags: list, for-loop, rbind

I have a list of 107 csv files (3560 rows x 13 columns) and I want to combine them in one long data frame `final_df`. They share the same structure but the last three columns are labelled differently in each file.

```
A = c("one", "two", "three","four","five") 
B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
C = c(34,11,3,45,65)
D = c(7,1,88,95,13)
J_1 = c(23,6,8,15,54)
J_2 = c(2,54,69,95,45)
J_3 = c(9,10,11,5,14)
W_1 = c(23,6,8,15,54)
W_2 = c(2,54,69,95,45)
W_3 = c(9,10,11,5,14)

file_1 <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,J_1,J_2,J_3)
file_2 <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,W_1,W_2,W_3)
```

I tried to list them and pass them through a for loop where I could change the row name with a fixed vector (colnames), in order to have the same column names and be able to use the function rbind, but no luck.

```
colnames = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "X_1", "X_2", "X_3")
names(i) <- colnames
```

Furthermore, I wanted to add an extra column `final_df$filename` storing the file name (possibly without the path and the .csv), not to lose information on the origin of the data.

My expected result would ideally look like this:

```
      A B  C  D X_1 X_2 X_3 filename
1    one 1 34  7  23   2   9   file_1
2    two 2 11  1   6  54  10   file_1
3  three 3  3 88   8  69  11   file_1
4   four 4 45 95  15  95   5   file_1
5   five 5 65 13  54  45  14   file_1
6    one 1 34  7  23   2   9   file_2
7    two 2 11  1   6  54  10   file_2
8  three 3  3 88   8  69  11   file_2
9   four 4 45 95  15  95   5   file_2
10  five 5 65 13  54  45  14   file_2
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed with the code below, even if I had to keep the .csv in the file name.

Solution:

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.csv$", all.files=FALSE,full.names =TRUE)

final_df <- c()

columnnames <- colnames = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "X_1", "X_2", "X_3")

for(i in 1:length(list_of_files)){
  
  file <- list_of_files[i]
  var <- read.csv(file)
  names(var) <- columnnames
  var$filename <-paste(sapply(strsplit(as.character(list_of_files[i]),'_'), "[", 13))
  final_df <- rbind(final_df,var)
}
```